# Website backup.zip File on Hosting Server is safe from hacker or Robot?

Tags: php, hosting, server

Many people Make their website backup.zip on their hosting server,

A zip file are place on same directory where Index.php exists.

So if i use this link my backup will download  `http://www.example.com/backup.zip`

If I don't share my backup filename/link, is it safe from hackers or robots?

Is there any function that give my all files and directory name?

How to secure backup.zip file on hosting server?

> I post this question here because I think Developers know best about
>   Hacking / robots attack / get directory / get files from another server

Comment: I'd never call that zip `backup`. It's a too obvious name. You could restrict access to zip files with .htaccess to deny unauthorized access.

Answer (score 2):

There is many way to protect your files from the eyes of internet.

The simplest one is to have a index.html, index.html, or index.php file, into the directory who contain your backup.zip, but the file still can be acceded if someone guess his name and call it from his URL like this: www.example.com/backup.zip

To avoid this issue: most of the webservers provide a way to protect your file. If we  assume you are under Apache2 you must create a rule into a .htaccess file (who is located into the same directory of your file) to prevent people from accessing your backup.zip.

e.g:

```
<Files backup.zip>
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

if you are not under Apache2, you could find the answer by checking the documentation of your HTTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not safe as it is, as `/backup.zip` is the most obvious path that hackers can guess.

So to protect the zip file from unauthorised access, move it to the separate folder and create `.htaccess` with the following content:

```
Deny from all   
# Turn off all options we don't need.
Options None
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

To make this work, your Apache needs to use mod_rewrite with option `AllowOverride All` for that folder to allow the `.htaccess` file to be run (which usually it is configured by default).